# Dopo "tipi di" va un plurale o un singolare?

Tags: grammatical-number

In una frase come:

> Sono presenti vari tipi di **[categoria]**

dove **[categoria]** può essere un sostantivo qualunque ("animale/i", "auto", "persona/e", "merce/i", "benefit"), esiste una convenzione per il numero di questo sostantivo?

In ciascuno degli esempi che riporto (laddove è possibile una scelta) entrambe le possibilità mi suonano bene, ma non vorrei sbagliare o ignorare che la scelta si porta dietro eventuali connotazioni di significato.

Comment: Io ho visto questa costruzione sia con il plurale sia con il singolare. Per esempio, in [questo articolo dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tipi-di-testo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) si può leggere "tipi di testo", "tipi di costruzione", "tipi di composizione" e "tipi di restrizione". In [quest'altro articolo dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) si trovano invece le espressioni "tipi di predicati", "tipi di verbi" e "tipi di informazioni".

Comment: Per una questione simile in inglese si trova [qualcosa](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv310.shtml) (anche qui ci sono gli esempi "types of music" e "types of jigs"), ma non ho trovato nulla sull'italiano.

Comment: Altri esempi di uso di "tipi di" + singolare o plurale si trovano nel corpo di questa domanda: [Tipi di + singolare/plurale - Citazioni tratte da fonti attendibili](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9804/tipi-di-singolare-plurale-citazioni-tratte-da-fonti-attendibili).

Answer (score 1):

Questo tipo di costruzione è utilizzata correttamente sia al singolare che al plurale in molti ambiti, come ha fatto notare @Charo nel suo commento.

Aggiungo che tale situazione sembra ricadere nei cosiddetti ***problemi di accordo*** (in questo caso del numero), un insieme di casistiche tra cui si può notare anche l'utilizzo della  ***[concordanza a senso](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza-a-senso_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)*** detta anche ***[sillessi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sillessi)***.

Sebbene Treccani indichi solo due casi tra i più comuni, ho trovato in questo interessante documento [riguardante le concordanze nel genere e nel numero](http://www.oblique.it/images/formazione/dispense/concordanze_gabrielli.pdf) un passaggio che, dopo aver analizzato un gran numero di casi problematici, recita:

> Da questa sintetica rassegna dei casi più controversi, sembra emergere
>   una tendenza diffusa verso la cosiddetta “concordanza a senso” e in
>   direzione di un allentamento della norma, fondata spesso sull’esempio
>   degli usi letterari che prevedeva un rigido accordo grammaticale,
>   anche quando il genere e il numero logico non corrispondesse a questo.

Comment: Scusa, non ho capito bene il nesso con la domanda. In “sono presenti vari tipi di animale/i” dov'è il problema di concordanza? Mi sembra che “tipi” concordi con “sono” indipendentemente dal numero di “animale/i”. Che cosa mi sfugge?

Comment: Anche se questo non è un problema di concordanza in senso stretto, volevo solo far notare il concetto per cui in assenza di una regola precisa si usa procedere a senso. Avrei potuto iniziare la mia risposta con "Questo tipo di costruzioni sono utilizzate" oppure "Questo tipo di costruzioni sono utilizzate" e suonerebbe comunque bene.

Comment: A me personalmente “Questo tipo ... sono utilizzate” suona come un chiodo su una lavagna, ma devo essere io. Tornando a noi, come si applica il discorso di “procedere a senso” al problema di “tipi di animale/animali”?

Comment: Hai ragione, ho sbagliato volevo scrivere questi tipi di costruzione o questi tipi di costruzioni... Il procedere a senso si applica verificando in primo luogo che l'uso di "tipi di animale/animali" non pregiudichi il senso della frase e poi che la frase suoni bene