# Tipi di + singolare/plurale - Citazioni tratte da fonti attendibili

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Vorrei capire se dopo *tipi di* va messo il singolare o il plurale; la mia domanda presenta un punto in più rispetto a questa:

[Dopo "tipi di" va un plurale o un singolare?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/dopo-tipi-di-va-un-plurale-o-un-singolare)

in quanto richiedo anche di inserire una sorta di bibliografia (preferibilmente contenente riferimenti a libri di grammatica) usata per rispondere alla domanda di partenza.

Qui ad esempio si usa il plurale (tipi di subordinate):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/ma-domande-sono-queste

Qui si usa il plurale (tipi di problemi):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/problemi-accordo

Qui si usa il plurale (tipi di contenuti):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/piazza-delle-lingue

Qui si usa il plurale (tipi di nomi):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/alcune-particolarit-sulluso-nomi-propri

Qui si usa il plurale (tipi di elencazioni):

http://www-old.accademiadellacrusca.it/faq/faq_risp.php%3Fid=4309&ctg_id=44.html

Qui si usa il singolare (tipi di accento):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/vademecum-sullaccento-indicarlo-pronunciarlo

Qui si usa il singolare (tipi di comunicazione):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/scritture-tachigrafiche

Qui si usa il singolare (tipi di struttura):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/concetti-frase-enunciato-periodo-proposizion

Qui si usa il singolare (tipi di ricerca):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/scaffali-digitali/per-lessico-artistico-testi-xviii-xx-secolo

Qui si usa il singolare (tipi di produzione):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/congiuntivo

Qui si usa il singolare (tipi di interrogazione):

http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/attivita/proverbi-italiani-unampia-banca-dati-fine-cinquecento-oggi

Grazie per la disponibilità.

Comment: Vuoi dire alcuni esempi tratti di libri di grammatica?

Comment: Ciao @Charo, nella seconda parte della domanda chiedo di fornire riferimenti bibliografici perché io ne sono sprovvisto.

Comment: Riferimenti bibliografici a testi che trattino questo aspetto? Ti posso assicurare che, quando è stata posta la domanda precedente, li abbiamo cercati e non ne abbiamo trovato nessuno.

Comment: Sì, cerco proprio quelli. Deve necessariamente esistere qualcosa in merito in quanto ogni aspetto della grammatica italiana viene giustificato sempre rigorosamente dai linguisti.

Comment: Sembra che i fatti dimostrino che sono ammesse entrambe le costruzioni, no?

Comment: E io non sono completamente sicura che si possa considerare veramente una domanda diversa dall'altra: nelle risposte  (perlomeno in quelle che sono considerate buone risposte) cerchiamo di fare riferimento a fonti affidabili che trattino l'aspetto di cui stamo parlando. Se  in quell'altra domanda non c'è una risposta con tali fonti è semplicemente perché finora nessuno le ha trovate.

Comment: Infatti gli unici riferimenti da me trovati sono in [questo documento](http://www.oblique.it/images/formazione/dispense/concordanze_gabrielli.pdf) che contiene diversi riferimenti bibilografici a Garzanti Linguistica e tra gli altri questo riferimento dell'[Accademia della Crusca riguardante i problemi di accordo](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/printpdf/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/problemi-accordo).

Comment: Salve Gennaro e grazie per l'interessamento al tema (sono l'autore dell'"altra domanda") e per aver compilato una lista di fonti utili a risolvere il problema. Credo sinceramente che quello di fornire riferimenti bibliografici sia uno sforzo implicitamente richiesto a chi risponde a una domanda, per cui la tua e la mia domanda mi sembrano in realtà coincidenti

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @NicolaSap e, per questa ragione, io chiuderei questa domanda come duplicato, ma vorrei sapere l'opinione di altri utenti. Tenete conto che, se si chiude come duplicato, questa domanda non sparirà: semplicemente se qualcuno riesce a scrivere una risposta basata in qualche fonte attendibile lo farà come risposta all'altra domanda.

Comment: Va bene, sono d'accordo con voi sull'etichettare la domanda come duplicato. Se possibile vorrei suggerirvi di inserire gli esempi presenti in questa domanda (o questo link https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9804/tipi-di-singolare-plurale-citazioni-tratte-da-fonti-attendibili?noredirect=1#comment21805_9804) nella domanda di NicolaSap.

Comment: Il link è incorporato automaticamente: vedi la sezione "Linked" nella domanda [Dopo “tipi di” va un plurale o un singolare?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8516/707). Tuttavia ho aggiunto un commento indicando che in questa domanda si possono trovare tali esempi.